# Assembly 8086 mouse second input issue

Tags: assembly, input, mouse, x86-16

im working on project to school. My project is a Calculator which includes some elemntaric actions. I Drew a BitMap and loades it into the screen, once i ask for input everything works fine. In the second time im asking to input nothing happens
im attaching the relevantic procedures
Thank you alot

```
`proc ActiveMouse
push ax
xor ax,ax
int 33h;starting mouse
mov ax,1
int 33h;Mouse Pointer active
pop ax
ret
endp ActiveMouse


proc getClick
push ax
push bx
push dx
push cx
ror bx,1
LeftClickStatus:
rol bx,1
mov ax,3h
int 33h;get click status
ror bx,1
jnc LeftClickStatus
mov [word ptr YCoordinate],dx;dx is max 200
mov ax,cx
mov cx,2
xor dx,dx
div cx
mov [XCoordinate],ax
pop cx
pop dx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
endp getClick`
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you provided doesn't contain much for the problem you might have.
Below are some observations though:

> ```
> proc ActiveMouse
>  push ax
>  xor ax,ax
>  int 33h;starting mouse
>  mov ax,1
>  int 33h;Mouse Pointer active
>  pop ax
>  ret
> endp ActiveMouse
> ```

The *ActiveMouse* procedure should also preserve `BX` as the `AX`=0 call returns a button count in it.

---

> ```
> mov ax,cx
> mov cx,2
> xor dx,dx
> div cx
> mov [XCoordinate],ax
> ```

Why don't you simplify this division by 2 ???

```
shr cx, 1
mov [XCoordinate], cx
```

---

> ```
> ror bx,1
> LeftClickStatus:
> rol bx,1
> ```

These `BX` manipulations don't do anything useful. `BX` is returned by the `AX`=3 call, but is not one of its input parameters.

---

Make sure the *GetClick* procedure has access to the `DS` segment. If required use a segment override prefix on:

```
mov [cs:YCoordinate], dx
mov [cs:XCoordinate], cx
```